# Remove item from list of records

Tags: clojure

I'm have a following structure:

```
(defrecord Member [id name salary role])  
(defrecord Project [id name duration])
(defrecord ProjectMember [project member])

(def project-member-records (ref ()))

(defn find-project-member-record [parm-proj-id parm-member-id]
  (filter #(let [project (.project %) 
             member (.member %) 
             proj-id (:id project)
             member-id (:id member)] 
             (and (= proj-id parm-proj-id)
                  (= member-id parm-member-id))) @project-member-records))

;;Sample func, does not work
(defn remove-project-member-record [proj-id member-id]
  (dosync (ref-set project-member-records (remove #(= (:id (.project %)) proj-id) @project-member-records))))
```

Now, i want to remove item from `project-member-records`. For instance, i want to remove item by project id and member id, like i'm finding record in `find-project-member-record` function. Or (and) i want remove item than i have record found by `project-member-records`, something like `(remove (find-project-member-record 1 1) project-records) ;pseudo code`But i dont know how i can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `remove` is correct, but `find-project-member-record` returns a sequence. Try

```
(defn remove-project-member-record [proj-id member-id]
  (let [it (first (find-project-member-record proj-id member-id))]
    (dosync
     (ref-set project-member-records
              (remove #(= % it) @project-member-records)))))
```

If `find-project-member-record` always returns either an empty sequence or a sequence with one item, it may make sense for it to instead return either the item itself or `nil`. (e.g., call `first` on  the result of `filter` in `find-project-member-record` rather than in `remove-project-member-record` and elsewhere).

Here's how you can structure it if you want everything to be wrapped in the `dosync` transaction:

```
(defn remove-project-member-record [proj-id member-id]
  (dosync
   (let [it (first (find-project-member-record proj-id member-id))]
     (ref-set project-member-records
              (remove #(= % it) @project-member-records)))))
```

Comment: Sorry, but it does not work. I rewrote a little your sample: `(defn remove-project-member-record [proj-id member-id]
  (dosync 
    (ref-set project-member-records 
             (remove #(= % (first (find-project-member-record proj-id member-id))) @project-member-records))))` This code dont throw any errors, but not removing data from list.

Comment: @OZKA, I had a syntax error in there, sorry about that. Try it again now - it works in my testing. Also, while your rewrite would normally be equivalent, it isn't in this case (because it's in a transaction). That's why my formulation works but yours doesn't.

Comment: @OZKA, if you need everything to be wrapped in the transaction, move the `let` to within the `dosync`, that works on my end too.